# How to get two edit text boxes side by side through java code?

Tags: android

**Problem solved**

**now i want to define one edit text to left and other to right...
i tried doing that but didnt work.. when i do fill_parent.. it just show one edit text.. on one line where it shows both of them side by side when i do wrap_content..
now what i want to do is.. have both edit text boxes define certain size and position left and right.. which i tried implementing didnt work??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new linear layout, add the EditTexts to that, then add the new linear layout to your existing layout.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText t = new EditText(PlusbuttonActivity.this);
    EditText a = new EditText(PlusbuttonActivity.this);
    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(PlusbuttonActivity.this);

    t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    a.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    l.addView(t);
    l.addView(a);
    addViewToRoot(l);
}
```

Basically, you're just reproducing the same structure you would need to produce the layout in your XML.

Comment: fill parent other one doesnt show up..
 t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             a.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

i use wrap_content for both.. but lets say i want to define there positions.. one to be on left and one to be on right.. can i do that??

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand the question - maybe update your question to include more detail. In any case, anything you can do in XML can be done in Java. There are Java equivalents to all of the XML types and attributes. Once you figure it out in XML, the Java part is easy - add nested elements to parent elements, set attributes to match the XML, and it should just work.

Comment: i edited the code.. 

i tried implementing gravity, width and height part.. but didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the layout from vertical to horizontal in your layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            ...
```

You can also position elements within the layout using the [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3agravity) setting.  So to position the button in the middle you could use:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        ...
```

**Update**: to put two buttons in each row, side by side, simply nest the LinearLayout elements, e.g.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ...>
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ...>
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
  </LinearLayout> 
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ...>
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: lol... to do it linear i got it but it will show like <edittext><edittext> i dont want that.. 

i two edit text boxes side by side ....and next two below than...
than below that..

Comment: its a button.. once u click two edit text boxes should pop up and now i want them in the form as i shown b4...

Comment: Ok, I see you've updated the original question now.  Maybe you need to set the  LayoutParams to both be LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, as the FILL_PARENT will use up the whole row.

Comment: ummm bro.. i get that...

its the output form.. look at the <edit text> <edit text> format i have shown.. i want that... wrap content will just shrink the edittext... nothing else.. i want that format

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong?  Are two buttons being added each time, but vertically?  Or are only two buttons ever shown?  FILL_PARENT will make the button try to fill the entire width of the row, so I think that needs to be WRAP_CONTENT.  Also, I think your LinearLayout XML should be android:layout_height="wrap_content", otherwise each row will try to fill the entire height of the parent view.

Comment: GOTO10 understood what i was trying to say.. thanks alot man.. i respect that you took out time and showed so mch efforts.. now i just need to define the size of the edit text and postition.. in layout params.. lets c how i can do that... ?? if you got any clue please help :)

Comment: I USED  t.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);... DIDNT WORK OUT..:(